# Disable Volume rocker so it can be used to control a game

Tags: android, button, volume

Hi Im making a snake game as a beginner android project and one of the feature i would like to have is making the Volume Control Keys control the snake.  I wrote the code to handle the control but when I try to play the game it comes up with the volume menu instead of controlling the snake. I was wondering if there was some way to override the original actions of the volume keys. 
Heres the part of the code where I handle the controls

```
      @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
        if (mMode == READY) {
            /*
             * At the beginning of the game, or the end of a previous one,
             * we should start a new game.
             */
            initNewGame();
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }

        if (mMode == PAUSE) {
            /*
             * If the game is merely paused, we should just continue where
             * we left off.
             */
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }

        if (mMode == PAUSED) {
            /*
             * If the game is merely paused by the user then we shall tell them their score, we should just continue where
             * we left off.
             */
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }


        if (mDirection != SOUTH) {
            mNextDirection = NORTH;
        }
        return (true);
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        if (mMode == RUNNING) {
            /*
             * At the beginning of the game, or the end of a previous one,
             * we should start a new game.
             */
            setMode(PAUSED);
            update();
            return (true);
        }
        if (mMode == PAUSED) {
            /*
             * If the game is merely paused by the user then we shall tell them their score, we should just continue where
             * we left off.
             */
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }



    }



    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
        if (mMode == READY) {
            /*
             * At the beginning of the game, or the end of a previous one,
             * we should start a new game.
             */
            initNewGameChaos();
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }

        if (mMode == PAUSED) {
            /*
             * If the game is merely paused by the user then we shall tell them their score, we should just continue where
             * we left off.
             */
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }




        if (mDirection != NORTH) {
            mNextDirection = SOUTH;
        }
        return (true);




    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
        if (mMode == READY) {
            /*
             * At the beginning of the game, or the end of a previous one,
             * we should start a new game.
             */
            initNewGameHard();
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }
        if (mMode == PAUSED) {

            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }



        if (mDirection != EAST) {
            mNextDirection = WEST;
        }
        return (true);
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
        if (mMode == READY) {

            initNewGameEasy();
            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }
        if (mDirection != WEST) {
            mNextDirection = EAST;
        }

        if (mMode == PAUSED) {

            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }

        return (true);
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
        if (mMode == LOSE) {

            setMode(READY);
            update();
            return (true);
        }
        if (mMode == RUNNING) {

            setMode(PAUSED);
            update();
            return (true);
        }
        if (mMode == PAUSED) {

            setMode(RUNNING);
            update();
            return (true);
        }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        if (mDirection == WEST) {
            mNextDirection = SOUTH;
        }
        if (mDirection == SOUTH) {
            mNextDirection = EAST;
        }
        if (mDirection == EAST) {
            mNextDirection = NORTH;
        }
        if (mDirection != NORTH) {
            mNextDirection = WEST;
        }
            if (mMode == PAUSED) {

                setMode(RUNNING);
                update();
                return (true);
            }
     return true;
      }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        if (mDirection == WEST) {
            mNextDirection = NORTH;
        }
        if (mDirection == NORTH) {
            mNextDirection = EAST;
        }
        if (mDirection == EAST) {
            mNextDirection = SOUTH;
        }
        if (mDirection != SOUTH) {
            mNextDirection = WEST;
        }
            if (mMode == PAUSED) {

                setMode(RUNNING);
                update();
                return (true);
            }

    return true;
    }



}     
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, msg);
}
```

Comment: can you post the method that contains this code? perhaps you are declaring it wrong or in the wrong place, but with just this part we wouldn't be able to tell.

Answer (score 4):

Return `true` after handling the volume keypress, instead of falling through to call the `super` method.

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
    // handle the keypress here
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Not really... "return `true` after handling the volume keypress" is about as simple as I can make it without actually writing your code for you.

Comment: Sigh... OK, there's an example of what you need to do. I really can't put it any more simply than that.